# How to split a field and then to print the last element using awk

Tags: awk, split, printing

I am trying to edit a file which has this format:

```
field1 field2 field3 gene_id "xxxxx"; transcript_id "XM_xxxxxxxx.x"; db_xref "GeneID:102885392"; exon_number "1";
```

I would like as output:

```
field1 field2 field3 exon_number "1";
```

I am using awk to do it, but I failed to print the last part of the last field after splitting it. Here is my code:

```
awk '{split($4,a,";"); print ($1, $2,$3, a[$NF])}' input
```

I know `a[$NF]` is not working, but how to indicate the last subfield; is it the last element of the array? (In my file exon_number is not always the 5th element, but always the last one).

Comment: I assume the `<\t>`s in your example represent literal tab characters. Please [edit] your question to state that if it's true, or state that it's a literal string otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exon_number "1"` is your 2nd-last `;`-separated subfield, not your last one since there's a null string after the last `;` you're splitting on.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {n=split($4,a,/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/); print $1, $2, $3, a[n-1]";"}' input
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {n=split($4,a,/[[:space:]]*;[[:space:]]*/); $4=a[n-1]";"; print}' input
```

See `split()` at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions

Answer (score 1):

```
$ STR='field1<\t>field2<\t>field3<\t>gene_id "xxxxx"; transcript_id "XM_xxxxxxxx.x"; db_xref "GeneID:102885392"; exon_number "1";'    

$ awk -F'; ' '{sub(/>[^>]*$/,">",$1); $0=$1 $NF}1' <<<"$STR"
field1<\t>field2<\t>field3<\t>exon_number "1";
```